# What the hell is a Gobbleshaft?

Tags: surgeon-simulator-2013

In the ultra-secret mission in *Surgeon Simulator 2013* I've presumably been abducted by aliens in order to perform surgery on one of them.  The only problem is that I've no idea how to perform a *Gobbleshaft transplant*.

I took out what I guess were the ribs, and some weird green and blue wormy thing, and what's left is pretty weird.  Which of these things is the Gobbleshaft?

[image: What is this I don't even]

Comment: Somebody didn't pay attention during the last semester of medical school.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Gobbleshaft:

[image: Gobbleshaft]

I dont have Surgeon Sim 2013 but my cousin does and she showed me all the six Alien surgeries!

Comment: That's like the second thing I removed, are you sure that's it?  Or are there more surgeries for different parts later on?

Comment: There are different parts later on.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Since it's a transplant, there should be another one lying somewhere on the table. Does it look like this picture? :P

Comment: the "object to trnasplant" changes each time you start the activity. all of the possible transplants are in the tubes surrounding the alien.

Comment: @Fluttershy and JLaBella, you are correct, its on the left of the alien on a table.

Comment: Just realised! The gobbleshaft is on the middle left of the picture in the question!!!!

Comment: It was in a tube.  In my picture, the one you can see on the table is the old one that I removed.